# Delegation vs. Message Passing

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, message-passing

I have a class, call it `A` that parses some data out in an `NSDictionary`. That class has a table view, and when a cell is selected, a new class instantiates, let's call that class `B`. Class `B` in turn instantiates class `C`. I want class `C` to receive the `NSDictionary` that was created in `A`.

Would delegates work? Would it work even though class `C` isn't instantiated? If that's true and it really does not, should I pass the data from `A`-->`B`-->`C` in the `init` method? Are there better message passing methods in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I pass the data from A-->B-->C in the init method?

I think that's the best plan.

A really shouldn't have to worry about how B does what it does. The fact that B uses C is none of A's business. All A needs to know is that B needs the dictionary in order to do it's thing.

As it happens, B doesn't care all that much about the dictionary, but the dictionary should be part of B's job description, which is something like: *Take the data you're given and display it somehow.* If B deals with the dictionary by passing it directly to C, that's fine -- not something A should care about.

You *could* do the same thing with a delegate. A could give B a reference to itself as a data source, and B could eventually pass that on to C. It's the same process you'd have with the dictionary, so there's no real advantage in doing that if you can put everything that C needs into the dictionary. You might consider switching to delegation if A doesn't know in advance exactly what data is needed, or when you want A to be able to somehow customize the behavior of C.

Comment: Thanks! When would one use a delegate then?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with passing it through the init. Alternatively depending on what kind of class "A" is. You could make it a singleton, or pass the parsed dictionary to a singleton, and then reference it directly from within "C".